# Why is "for" not used in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, ielts

why is *for* not used in this sentence :

> The number of persons jobless **(for)** 15 to 26 weeks declined by 188,000 to 1.2 million

Comment: What is the context? A headline, a bullet point, a sentence in a paragraph? I would agree that the **for** is necessary.

Comment: @randomhead:  it is in a report

Comment: Some headlines doesn't act as a normal grammar configuration. It has the grammar of its own. I mean if its a headline it doesn't actually follow the rules but a "***for***" is necessary

Comment: I don't think **for** is necessary at all; it's optional in a construction like this.  For example, ["Katie has been dead twenty years"](https://books.google.com/books?id=j-pE35dkmj4C&pg=PA31&dq=%22been+dead+twenty+years%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjG8bOistbwAhWaEFkFHallBL8Q6AEwAnoECAkQAg)

Comment: The jobless numbers at weeks 15 to 26 are x.